# Ignoring non-existent URLs with htmlParse() in R

Tags: r, html-parsing, web-scraping

G'day Everyone,

I have a very long list of place names (~15,000) that I want to use to look up wiki pages and extract data from them. Unfortunately not all of the places have wiki pages and when htmlParse() hits them it stops the function and returns an error.

```
    Error: failed to load HTTP resource
```

I can't go through and remove every place name that creates a non-existent URL so I was wondering if there is a way to get the function to skip places that don't have a wiki page?

```
    # Town names to be used
    towns <- data.frame('recID' = c('G62', 'G63', 'G64', 'G65'), 
                    'state' = c('Queensland', 'South_Australia', 'Victoria', 'Western_Australia'),
                    'name'  = c('Balgal Beach', 'Balhannah', 'Ballan', 'Yunderup'),
                    'feature' = c('POPL', 'POPL', 'POPL', 'POPL'))

    towns$state <- as.character(towns$state)

    towns$name <- sub(' ', '_', as.character(towns$name))

   # Function that extract data from wiki
   wiki.tables <- function(towns)  {
      require(RJSONIO)
      require(XML)
      u <- paste('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',
                 sep = '', towns[,1], ',_', towns[,2])
      res <- lapply(u, function(x) htmlParse(x))
      tabs <- lapply(sapply(res, getNodeSet, path = '//*[@class="infobox vcard"]')
             , readHTMLTable)
      return(tabs)
    }

    # Now to run the function. Yunderup will produce a URL that 
    # doesn't exist. So this will result in the error.
    test <- wiki.tables(towns[,c('name', 'state')])

    # It works if I don't include the place that produces a non-existent URL.
    test <- wiki.tables(towns[1:3,c('name', 'state')])
```

Is there a way to identify these non-existent URLs and either skip them or remove them?

Thanks for you help!

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: Maybe an `if` statement inside the function to tell it to move to the next url if missing?

Comment: Running your code, I actually get the following error: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"XMLNodeSet"’`, not a URL-related error.

Comment: G'day Thomas, thanks I just realised the same thing. It is because the Yunderup URL that is created exists but doesn't have the table in it, e.g. path = '//*[@class="infobox vcard"]'. I am trying to figure out how to put an if statement checking whether the html data I get has this path... As the answer bellow shows, the URL does exist, but it isn't the 'right' type of wiki page that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option that uses the `httr` package. (BTW: you don't need `RJSONIO`). Replace your `wiki.tables(...)` function with this:

```
wiki.tables <- function(towns)  {
  require(httr)
  require(XML)
  get.HTML<- function(url){
    resp <- GET(url)
    if (resp$status_code==200) return(htmlParse(content(resp,type="text")))
  }
  u <- paste('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',
             sep = '', towns[,1], ',_', towns[,2])
  res <- lapply(u, get.HTML)
  res <- res[sapply(res,function(x)!is.null(x))]   # remove NULLs
  tabs <- lapply(sapply(res, getNodeSet, path = '//*[@class="infobox vcard"]')
                 , readHTMLTable)
  return(tabs)
}
```

This runs one GET request and tests the status code. The disadvantage of `url.exists(...)` is that you have to query every url twice: once to see if it exists, and again to get the data.

Incidentally, when I tried your code the Yunderup url does in fact exist ??

Comment: Thanks jlhoward. Yeah I realised a little while after that the url does exist, it is the getNodeSet, path ='//*[@class="infobox vcard"]', that doesn't. So I really have two levels of parsing to do. Get rid of those places that don't have URL, which you have provided a great solution for, and only extracting tabs from those URL where it is appropriate. I will be trying to figure out the second step soon, probably with an if statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
You can use the 'url.exists' function from `RCurl`

require(RCurl)
u <- paste('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',
                 sep = '', towns[,'name'], ',_', towns[,'state'])
> sapply(u, url.exists)
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balgal_Beach,_Queensland 
                                                    TRUE 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balhannah,_South_Australia 
                                                    TRUE 
           http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballan,_Victoria 
                                                    TRUE 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yunderup,_Western_Australia 
                                                    TRUE
```